# WatchKit get data from closed App in iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

There are some applications (example Runtastic) where is possible from the Watch to activate some function of the companion App even if the App is not running in the iPhone (never opened or closed). How is possible to make the same with my Apps (get general data or settings)? I read some documents from Apple about app in background but I don't find nothing about App closed. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the app in background visible on double press on home buttons? Because probably there is something wrong in my App...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few choices here: open the parent iPhone app to the background using `openParentApplication:reply:` in `WKInterfaceController`, use shared app containers or use app groups to share `NSUserDefaults` and keychain items. This will work for WatchKit 1 apps and here is an article on how to use these (+ `MMWormhole`): http://www.kristinathai.com/watchkit-best-practices-for-sharing-data-between-your-watch-and-ios-app/

One thing to keep in mind is when watchOS 2 launches later in this fall, this won't work with WatchKit 2 apps anymore. There you need `WCSession`, but that is a completely different thing and question.

Comment: Thanks.. Yes I know the new WCSession.. Should be more easy to make communication with the iPhone . About openparentApplication : I used it to send and receive data but does it work even if the phone is locked?

Comment: I didn't find any official information about that, but it most likely will work even if the phone is locked. To be sure, you can simply test it. I have watchOS 2 on my Apple Watch so I can't test that.

Comment: Thanks very much... now I create a very stupid App where from the watch I ask a number in the App and it works also if the App is closed and if the Phone is locked...